# Creating indexList without sections on tableView?

Tags: swift, indexing, tableview

My tableview has one section with an array beings displayed as rows. I am trying to create an indexlist that appears on the right hand side that I can customize, and will jump to a certain row. So far, I am able to have the index be shown, but it does not jump to a specific row when a letter is clicked. It will jump back to the first row when "A" is pressed, but none of the other index choices work. Is there a workaround for this?

Edit: Have been researching an answer, and still cannot find a way to go about this.

```
   let respiratory = ["A - Patient Disposition Form","B - On Scene Physician","C - APGAR Score","D - LA Prehospital Stroke Screen","E - Pain Scales","F - Restraint Checklist","G - Abbreviations","H - Reperfusion Checklist","I - Difficult Airway","J - Burn Resources","DNR","NCCEP Airway Evaluation Form","NC MOST Form","PREMIS Preliminary Report","NC Eye Bank"]

        let indexList = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","AA"]

        func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
            return indexList;
        }
        func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView( for tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]! {
            return respiratory as [AnyObject]
        }
 @IBOutlet weak var animalTableView: UITableView!




    ///Set elements in cell
    func tableView(  _ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "appendicieslist"/*Identifier*/, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = respiratory[indexPath.row]
        // FONT STYLE
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.animalTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        return cell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return respiratory.count
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The catch is that you're using a table view containing one section with many rows (instead of many sections with one row), but the index operates by reference to sections not rows.

From the [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) class documentation:

> A table view can have an index that appears as a bar on the right hand side of the table (for example, "A" through "Z"). You can touch a particular label to **jump to the target section**.

Once you've moved to a section-based table view, you can achieve finer-grained control over the navigation offered by the index by implementing the optional function [`tableView(_:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614933-tableview).

It always remains possible to code your own custom index that duplicates the functionality of the UITableView index for rows instead of sections, but that may well be inefficient or inappropriate depending on your use case.

Comment: So the best thing for me to do is reorganize my tableview into sections and rows per section?

Comment: Well, the only way for you to use the section index offered by UITableView is to reorganise your table view into sections. That's probably the simplest thing for you to do unless you're building a relatively sophisticated app or you're an experienced developer. Other approaches would require you to spend an amount of time and effort building or incorporating a custom-built table view index such as [MYTableViewIndex](https://github.com/mindz-eye/MYTableViewIndex).

Comment: @wcdean217 How did you go?

Answer (score 0):

It's hacky, but I think you could add a defer statement at the top of `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` that would handle the transition. Not sure if it would look great in a large list, but could be worth experimenting with.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
    defer { 
        // Handle transition to the correct row here
    }
    return 0 // Only one section so return it
}
```